# conditional infixes are deprecated in unified syntax

Tags: assembly, arm, conditional-statements, predicate, gnu-assembler

how to rework the "conditional infixes" for the ARM Thumb assembler?

the error "**conditional infixes are deprecated in unified syntax**" has happened as an output of the GNU Tools ARM (thumb) assembler on the following directives set:

```
    IT PL
    MOVPL   r14,#0x80000000     @ r14=0x80000000
```

or

```
    IT VS
    MOVVSS  r7,r14              @ DiffR=SAT(R-RightDC)
```

or

```
    IT VS
    MOVVSS  r6,r14              @ DiffL=SAT(L-LeftDC)
```

Comment: Perhaps it wants you to write `movsvs` (with the predicate last, after the `s`)?

Comment: @PeterCordes is correct, for GNU assembler the `S` is not last. However, noticed that Keil might not work that way, I have seen in a book that recommended putting the `S` as last where they talk about Keil exclusively. The Arm documents often prefer Keil as well as they purchased them in 2005. What I'm trying to say that you might be reading documents/manual which might fit the GNU Assembler in many ways while not being it for GNU Assembler. And there will be cases where the information can't be applied on the GNU Assembler and this might be one of the cases.

Comment: For example "Arm Assembly Language Programming & Architecture - Second Edition" by Muhammad Ali Mazidi et al. 2016 states the following on page 152: `Note that the 'S' suffix and the condition suffix are independent of each other. We can add both 'S' and condition suffix to the opcode of an instruction. It is common to put 'S' after the condition.`. On page 9 states `We have used the Keil Compiler for the programs throughout this book.` So they used it for example programs, but in essence their ISA description (and non-example parts of the document) are from Keil perspective only.

Comment: And there are cases of changing syntax as well, for example page 25: `Notice that in most instructions like ADD and SUB, Rn can be omitted if the Rd and Rn are the same. This format is no longer recommended by Unified Assembler Language.`. So you can see recommendations which do not apply to your toolchain at all, our that they were recomended at some point but are not any longer.